# Simulate a Tab keypress on Enter and on button element trigger form submit angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this angular code whereby I have a form and i want upon enter being clicked, it simulates a tab keypress and focuses on the next input. When it gets to the last input, it looks for the button element and then it triggers the ng-submit for the form But for some reasons, angularjs doesnt catch my trigger click function. Does anyone know how to get this done? This is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qujoy4sp/4/

This is my directive.js

```
app.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
      $timeout(function() {

        if(attrs.myEnter!= "undefined") {
          event.preventDefault();
          var elementToFocus = element.parent().next().find('button');
            angular.element( elementToFocus[0]).triggerHandler('click');

        } else {
          if (keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var elementToFocus = element.parent().next().find('input');
            if(angular.isDefined(elementToFocus)) {
              elementToFocus[0].focus();
            }
          }
        }   
      })
        });
    };
});


app.directive('errorPopup', function($ionicPopup) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {data: '=errorPopup'},
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      element.bind("submit", function() {

        switch(attrs.errorPopup) {
          case 'loginData':
            if(!scope.data.orgCode.$valid) { 
              alert("code is needed")

            }
            else if(!scope.data.email.$valid || !scope.data.email.$error) { 
              alert("email is needed")
            }
            else if(!scope.data.password.$valid) { 
              alert("password is needed")
            }
            break;
        } 
      });
    }
  }
})
```

my login.html

```
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con"> 
    <div scroll="true">
      <form name="loginData" class="container ng-scope ng-invalid ng-pristine ng-invalid-required" error-popup="loginData" ng-submit= "loginData.$valid && doLogin(loginData)" novalidate>
        <div class= "list list-inset login-form">

          <label class="item item-input item-icon-left">
           <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
            <input type="text" name="orgCode" class="hijack-align form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="user.orgCode" placeholder="Organization Code" my-enter="undefined" required>
          </label>

          <label class="item item-input item-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
            <input type="email" name="email" class="hijack-align form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email Address" my-enter="undefined" required>
          </label>

          <label class="item item-input item-icon-left">
            <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
            <input type="Password" name="password" class="hijack-align form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-invalid-minlength" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Your Password" ng-minlength="8" my-enter="submitData" required>
          </label>
          <div class="login-btn">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng-disabled="submitted">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have some error checking to be done and i want to d it upon form submit hence the other directive called errorPopup but the main thing is to get it to submit the form when it is on the button element.

Answer (score 0):

The `.next()` element you get is a `<br>`, not `<label>` as you seem to expect. So call `.next()` twice, or better yet: replace the linebreak with CSS.

Also, you should probably call `elementToFocus[0].focus();`. I've updated your fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is selecting  tag, if you add another next() to it, you will get the label.

The best is to use css to replace the 
 tag, on your label tags

```
display:block;
```

The following example is shown using css,

http://jsfiddle.net/qd4kefsr/

In this example, I have removed the 
 tags and performed this line break using css.

Feel free to use whichever version of the solution you like